# WebDriverWait times out when run through Continuous Integration

Tags: selenium, timeout, integration, webdriverwait, continuous

I use the following code to check if an element is visible for my automated tests before interacting with them (Selenium/C#).

```
        public bool ElementVisible(IWebDriver driver, IWebElement element, int secondsToWait = 30, bool doNotFailTest = false)
    {
        try
        {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secondsToWait));
            wait.Until<IWebElement>(d =>
            {
                if (element.GetCssValue("display") != "none" && element.Size.Height > 0 && element.Size.Width > 0)
                {
                    return element;
                }

                return null;
            });

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            if (!doNotFailTest)
            {
                throw;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

The tests that use this method work every time, when I run tests on my PC. However, when I trigger the tests to be run on our build machine from TFS's Continuous Integration, only then does this method time out when called by my tests. Another point that might be worth noting is: this method works on other websites we test (both locally and through the CI). Just not this one website for some reason...

I have tried:

1. Running the tests locally on the build machine, cutting out the CI = no issue.
2. Increased the time out several times to greater values = method times out at the greater values.
3. Added Thread.Sleep wait before the above try/catch block (my reasoning for this stems from an issue I found on Browserstack whereby an AJAX injected element would not be found by this method alone without first adding an arbitrary wait before the WebDriverWait... which doesn't make sense to me because WebDriverWait is apparently the only thing I need to use to find AJAX injected elements (from what I've read anyway)).

As an aside, the reason I've made this method a bool is because not all of my tests should fail if certain elements aren't found. For example, our website rarely has the terms and conditions updated. When it does, a modal is presented to the user when logging in. We've left this as a manual test, but to prevent this modal from breaking the daily runs, we look for it and accept the terms if it's there (suppressing exceptions).

This timeout error relates to an element of the test we do actually want to find, it is the condition to pass our LogIn test by finding an element on our website that is only present when logged in. This element is injected with AJAX.

Better colleagues than me at CI can't pinpoint why this issue is occurring. Theoretically, the trigger from the CI is simply to initiate the test run - it has no other involvement in the running of the tests...?

I have observed that when triggering the test run from the CI to the build machine, when I VPN to the build machine, I expect to see the browser load up and the tests being conducted, but this is not the case. Maybe this is a factor? Perhaps I'm wrong but this behaviour seems like the tests are running on a headless browser? Yet we have not specified any settings to use a headless version of Chrome (v75).

If it was the case that testing through a headless browser throws timeout errors related to AJAX elements, other tests have passed after logging in - using other AJAX injected elements. It is only when any test calls this method, does it time out, when the run is triggered from the CI, on this specific website.

Very confusing!

Comment: can you add the full error `ElementNotInteractableException`?

Answer (score 0):

I created a JavaScript version of the WebDriverWait, added some debugging (Console.Error.WriteLine()) to output the element's computed styles. The display property was 'none'... however, when I log in manually, in Chrome's developer tools, it is 'block'. Weird.

The element I was looking for was a DIV container that has the class 'loggedin'. I instead passed through an element inside this container that would also only be displayed when logged in (a piece of text). This worked.

My WebDriverWait doesn't work with either of the elements, so I have to stick with this JavaScript alternative. One thing to note, however, is that the evaluation of the element's properties takes 5 seconds, so I've omitted setting an interval between checks.

```
    public bool ElementVisible(IWebDriver driver, By locator, int numberOfPolls = 10, bool doNotFailTest = false)
    {
        bool elementVisible = false;
        int pollCount = numberOfPolls;

Thread.Sleep(1000);

        while (!elementVisible && pollCount > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                // Takes 5 seconds to compute, bear this in mind when setting an interval or increasing the pollCount
                elementVisible = (bool)js.ExecuteScript("var display = window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0]).display; var height = window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0]).height; var width = window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0]).width; return (display != 'none' && height != 0 && width != 0);", driver.FindElement(locator));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }

            if (elementVisible)
            {
                break;
            }

            pollCount--;
        }

        if (!elementVisible)
        {
            if (!doNotFailTest)
            {
                throw new Exception("ElementVisible(): - element not visible.");
            }
        }

        return elementVisible;
    }
```